# Darknet Command to Return Model With Loaded Weights

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet

I use Yolo for object detection and get the bounding boxes from an image with `./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov2.cfg yolov2.weights image.jpg -dont_show -ext_output` command code. I know I can work with OpenCV but I would like to use Yolo9000 model and it does not have OpenCV implementation. I am still able to get results from Yolo9000 model with the previous command code but it loads the model weights every time I run. Instead, I want to load the model weights once and use the model as long as I want. Is there any command code to return the model with loaded weights? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the command line, but if you want to use the model in your code you should use darknet as a library and import it in your code, as described [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll-and-so-libraries) in the official darknet repository.
Another option if you just have a buunch of images is this (from the same url):

> To process a list of images data/train.txt and save results of
> detection to result.json file use: ./darknet detector test
> cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output -dont_show
> -out result.json < data/train.txt

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I need to use it continuously in a service so when I start the service, the model should be loaded at the very beginning and do object detection if any request arrives. With other Yolo models, I am able to load the model with cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet method but with Yolo9000, I am unable to get results with that method. I do not know what a dll is exactly but could you please guide me how to do that if it is what I really require?

Comment: Yolo9000 is not supported by OpenCV, so you cannot use it with OpenCV. A DLL is the windows equivalent for Unix SO, a shared library. Look at the repository I linked.